# What does it mean when a C pointer is in the middle of two variables and not associated to either side?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, syntax

What I've seen so far in examples are things like the below with no space between `*` and `x`.

```c
    int num = 10;
    int *x = &num;
```

However, there's this struct definition in code I am working with where the pointer is not directly next to `p`.

```c
    struct passwd * p = getpwuid(getuid());
```

Do the spaces on both sides make an important difference or is this just a syntactical alternative?

Is this specific to structs?

I learned the terms for pointers association to a variable with no luck on what the instance I've provided could mean.

Comment: It's a matter of style, there's no effect on behavior. Generally, spaces and line-breaks can be safely removed, (except for the last space between two letters, removing which would turn them into a single word).

Comment: Thank you! I figured it'd likely be a syntax issue given that it performs as expected otherwise. Glad to have the confirmation.

Comment: Related, here's a marvelous tool for helping decode difficult declarations: https://cdecl.org/